# Uber sandbox request response error 422 unprocessed entity

Tags: android, request, httpresponse, uber-api

Please I am having issues with the Uber sandbox request endpoint which always returns a 422 unprocessed entity error. My post request method:

```
SandboxRequestBody sandRequestBody = new SandboxRequestBody(UberStatus.ACCEPTED);

@POST("/v1/requests")
void postRequest(@Body SandboxRequestBody sandboxRequestBody, Callback<UberRequest> callback);
```

I sent the post with the scope 'request'; I do not know why I keep receiving this error or do I need to request full access permission for scope request on my developer dashboard, please help!

Comment: According to the API documentation, the reason for error code 422 is -- `Invalid request. The request body is parse-able however with invalid content or there are issues with a rider’s user account.` Are you sending the proper request?

Comment: Hello Saumik, thanks for the quick response, I am sending it with a token and a status, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I am not completely aware of the API documentation. Please read the document and more specifically the required fields for a Request message. :)